# How to get a random int in python 2.7

Tags: python

How can I get a random integer?
I've tried to `get()`
but it does not work.

```
def get():

    a = randomNumber()
    return a

print get()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/genindex-R.html Start with documentation for your python version ;)

Comment: If you are learning to code Python then you should really go for the latest version, Python 3.7 and not the depreciated version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `random` module

```
import random
number = random.randint(1,5)
print number
```